# Calculate angle of triangle Python

Tags: python, math, geometry, angle

I'm trying to find out the angle of the triangle in the following, I know it should be 90 degrees, however I don't know how to actually calculate it in the following:

[image]

Here's what I've tried:

```
angle = math.cos(7/9.899)
angleToDegrees = math.degrees(angle)

returns: 43.XX
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This gives the angle between A and C.  Look into the law of cosines.

Comment: If I were to use `tan` I get closer... `x = math.tan(7/7)` and then `math.degrees(x)` returns `89.2328896038`? why isn't this an even 90?

Comment: A single trigonometric function will only work if you already have a right angle in the triangle, and are trying to find a different angle. `math.tan` takes radians and gives a ratio.  `math.degrees` takes radians and gives degrees.  They giving you almost 90 is coincidental.

Comment: all of the trig functions convert between an angle and the ratio of two sides of a triangle. cos, sin, and tan take an angle in radians as input and return the ratio; acos, asin, and atan take a ratio as input and return an angle in radians. You only convert the angles, never the ratios.

Comment: As @Teepeemm explains, the ratio leg1/hypotenuse gives you the cosine of the angle adjacent to leg1 that is NOT the right angle. In this case, because the triangle is isosceles, 45 degrees.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's a little more compicated than that. You need to use the [law of cosines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines)

```
>>> A = 7
>>> B = 7
>>> C = 9.899
>>> from math import acos, degrees
>>> degrees(acos((A * A + B * B - C * C)/(2.0 * A * B)))
89.99594878743945
```

This is accurate to 4 significant figures. If you provide a more precise value of C, you get a more accurate result.

```
>>> C=9.899494936611665
>>> degrees(acos((A * A + B * B - C * C)/(2.0 * A * B)))
90.0
```

Comment: That worked great, you wouldn't mind explaining it a bit more though would you?

Comment: @ShannonHochkins, follow the link to wikipedia for the explanation. It's really off-topic for this site.

Comment: Why is it off topic? I asked how to calculate this, usually an answer is best when it has better descriptions rather than just the code.

Comment: @ShannonHochkins, because it's math. You could try asking for an explanation on math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3):

You can use this also.

```
print(str(int(round(math.degrees(math.atan2(x,y)))))+'°')
```

**This accepts two inputs as two heights of the triangle and you can get the output angle in proper degree format.**

Answer (score 0):

i think you're looking for math.acos not math.cos, you want to return the angle whose value is the ratio of those two sides. not take its cosine.

Comment: This just gave me an even 45.00

Comment: Trig functions are for when you have an angle of 90 degrees, and you're interested in some other angle.

Comment: @Teepeemm trig funcs are for all triangles, they are just simpler when a 90deg angle is involved.

Answer (score 0):

Trig functions will convert an angle into a length of a certain leg of a certain triangle.  In particular, the tangent is the ratio of the opposite side to the adjacent side.  `math.tan(7/7)` is the length of the right triangle opposite an angle of 1(=7/7) radian.  This length (~1.557) just happens to be near to the number of radians which is 90 degrees (pi/2 ~ 1.571).

As noted, you're looking for an inverse trig function to convert a length back into an angle.

Comment: is that not what math.degrees does? converting radians to degrees/angles

Comment: It does convert radians to degrees.  But tan(1) is not radians to begin with.  The fact that you are treating it as radians is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
import math
AB = float(input())
BC = float(input())

print(str(int(round(math.degrees(math.atan2(AB, BC)))))+'°')
```

Comment: This code assumes that OP's marked angle is 90degrees, and then gives the acute angle next to input "BC".